# vue ui showing Error: NO_MODULES when creating a project (windows)

Tags: vue.js, user-interface, babeljs, eslint

I could see the GUI on the browser when I run vue ui command, and then when creating a project, I selected the npm as the Package Manager from the dropdown list and on the Preset section I chose the default (babel, eslint), but when I click on Create Project button I get NO_MODULES error. I then checked the terminal to see this error below

`$ vue ui`

`Starting GUI...`

`Ready on http://localhost:8000`

> Error: NO_MODULES
>       at importProject (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli\node_modules@vue\cli-ui\apollo-server\connectors\projects.js:363:11)
>       at progress.wrap (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli\node_modules@vue\cli-ui\apollo-server\connectors\projects.js:355:12)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

`$ node --version`

v10.16.2

`$ vue --version`

@vue/cli 4.1.2

Please advise what should be done.

Comment: Did you run `npm i`?

Comment: I'm seeing this as well with node 12.16.1 and vue/cli 4.3.0

Comment: There are a bunch of suggestions in this thread: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2633

Answer (score 0):

Check your NODE_ENV

```
echo $NODE_ENV
NODE_ENV=development
```